# Problems running app on emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i am using android programming on eclipse and was making an app which runs successfully on by mobile, but i have problems running that app on my emulator.

I was going to post screen shots of my emulator and console window results but, i was lacking required reputations, anyways, i am pasting the console note here,

```
[2014-08-17 19:14:13 - Calculator] Android Launch!
[2014-08-17 19:14:13 - Calculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-08-17 19:14:13 - Calculator] Performing com.example.calculator.background_pic activity launch
[2014-08-17 19:14:16 - Calculator] Uploading Calculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-08-17 19:14:38 - Calculator] Installing Calculator.apk...
[2014-08-17 19:14:57 - Calculator] Success!
[2014-08-17 19:14:58 - Calculator] Starting activity com.example.calculator.background_pic on device emulator-5554
[2014-08-17 19:15:03 - Calculator] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.calculator/.background_pic }
```

seems like, everything is just working fine, except that on emulator, it shows,

"Unfortunately, Calculator has just stopped"

and in the botton an "ok" button is shown.
can anybody knows the solutions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

one thing you do is to launch emulator directly from ur windows - AVD manager

select the emulator and start the emulator after completing,

install the apk file.

hope this helps u

Answer (score 0):

you haven't detailed out about your API level that may help us to filter out other problems. i had the same problem & found solution that you may follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562413/unfortunately-androidfirst-has-stopped)